# handling multiple panel on one form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am trying to create a windows forms application which consist of two panels. Both of the panels consist of buttons and a text box.

Example:

```
panel 1 consists of btn1 and tb1
panel 2 consists of btn2 and tb2
```

When btn1 is clicked panel2 is visble and when btn 2 is clicked panel1 is visible.

Here is my code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
    panel2.Visible = true;            
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Visible = false;
    panel1.Visible = true;  
}
```

panel2 does not appear.

What should I do?

Comment: Is one Panel inside the other?

Comment: Are you sure that the `btn2_Click` method is bound to the `Click` event handler of `btn2`? Seems like this code should be working just fine.

Comment: not inside..panel1 is on the top of panel2

Comment: @Yuck - when I click on btn1 on panel1 I didn't see panel2.

Comment: I'd test by completely separating them in the Forms designer and seeing if it works the way you expect them to.

Comment: I'm thinking it's either the buttons aren't bound to the event or the names of the buttons aren't btn1 and btn2 (perhaps those buttons exist elsewhere.  I just created a new winforms solution and made 2 panels of the exact size, placed panel1 on panel2 and copied your exact code into the click events and it works perfectly.

Comment: The designer doesn't let you put one panel on top of another one.  The panel ends up being inside the panel.  You'll need View + (Other Documents) + Document Outline to fix that.  Drag the nested panel back to the form.

Comment: That makes sense then because what I did when I replicated this issue was that I just typed the location in the property sheet as opposed to drag and drop. Hence my panels would indeed be located in the same place but not one within the other.

Comment: Christopher - Can you explain little bit in detail the point which you trying to say.

Comment: i was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
    panel2.Visible = true; 
    panel2.BringToFront();   
}
```

Comment: Write some description also about `BringToFront()` and `SendToBack()` method. The quality of answer is very low.